# Firebase CLI - Suppress User Prompts

Tags: firebase, deployment, gcloud, firebase-cli

I am deploying a function via **firebase-cli** with a *minInstances* param as per [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions). This works, however there is now a user prompt to acknowledge the estimated costs:

```
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing . directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged . (230.66 KB) for uploading
⚠  functions: The following functions have reserved minimum instances. This will reduce the frequency of cold starts but increases the minimum cost. You will be charged for the memory allocation and a fraction of the CPU allocation of instances while they are idle.

    testFunctionInstances(us-central1): 2 instances, 1GB of memory each

With these options, your minimum bill will be $17.22 in a 30-day month
? Would you like to proceed with deployment? (y/N)
```

This new prompt is breaking our current deployment setup. We're currently looking at using **firebase-cli** to deploy functions in a "vanilla" state ie no additional runtime parameters, and then following up with **gcloud beta** to update a discrete list of existing functions with new runtime params; however, this adds new complexity to our CI/CD.

Is there a way to suppress these kinds of messages associated with financial estimates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning in question only appears when the estimated price is going up - after a single manual deploy if `minInstances` remains stable there will not be a prompt.

That being said, you can add the `--force` flag to the deploy which will suppress all prompting. Note that this includes prompting to delete functions missing from the deployment, so be careful when removing functions.

Comment: Using `--only` flag along side `--force` both avoids the prompt to delete functions and suppresses prompts, including the price estimate prompt. Thanks!

Comment: @Michael the documentation for that flag does NOT imply it controls prompts other than deleting cloud functions. My testing suggests you're correct, but it would have saved me considerable time if `firebase deploy --help` explained this.